# 'Object.keys called on non-object' error when upgrading bower from version 1.3.12 to version 1.4.1

Tags: npm, bower

After I ran `bower install`, I got a warning:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Update available: 1.4.1 (current: 1.3.12) │
│ Run npm update -g bower to update.        │
└───────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

If I follow the instruction and run the `update` command, I got a list of 'Object.keys called on non-object' error

```
> npm update  -g bower                                                                                                                                                 ✭ ✱
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.14

npm ERR! Object.keys called on non-object
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.14

npm ERR! Object.keys called on non-object
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ~/.npm and run `npm install -g bower` instead